# Have you ever encountered Wordpress settings that wouldn't stick?

Tags: wordpress

I'm in the middle of moving Wordpress from localhost on my local machine to the live web.  I modified the wp_options table's siteurl and home values to point to blog.site.com/.  It worked the first time I entered this url, but subsequent url entries would not display the blog page.

Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really straight forward to change the URL of a wordpress site after the initial install because the database contains references to the initial url.

Have you tried following the steps outlined in these pages?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change
http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

You can use this script to update the DB referees from the old url.
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: Ok, I'll try it and get back with you.

Comment: I used the online search and replace function to change all of the URLs in the sql dump file, then uploaded it to the new site and turned it on.  Worked like a charm. It not only does the search and replace, but it handles the serialization issue as well. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Once you change the url in the wp_options table and upload the new database, make sure the first thing you do is go into the live site and set your permalinks. Even if you just go in and click save. This should update the url accordingly. However, any links in the content areas, widgets, etc. will still need to be updated manually with the new domain.

There are also some tools to help with this type of migration. Haven't tried it yet, but have heard good things about [WP DB Migrate Pro](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/)

Comment: I didn't try the WP DB Migrate Pro, but I'll keep this page bookmarked for future references.  Thanks.